# Total number of paints or number of each paint

Tags: numbers

If I say

> We have a total of 10 paints in the following categories "
>
> 10 Matt and egg shell paints

Does that list make sense or does it read as if I have 10 Matt paints and 10 egg shell paints totaling 20 paints (the actual list is about 100 paints broken into categories).

Comment: If you say that you're confusing the heck out your reader.  You have 10 *categories* of paint.

Comment: The word total lets the reader know that you have 10 of matte or eggshell finish.

Comment: Maybe it’s 10 paints in the following category: Matte and eggshell. (Matte is a finish; is eggshell a finish, not a color?)

Comment: It does make sense but it's not very informative. It could mean that you have 9 matt and 1 eggshell, 1 matt and 9 eggshell or any combination in between. It would be better to be specific.

Comment: @BoldBen I agree with that but I only have a limited amount of space for the text and 100 paints so i am trying to break that down into manageable amounts.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say "we have a total of 10 paints" when you actually have 100.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Find ten apples and oranges' ... do I find 10 or 20?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166286/find-ten-apples-and-oranges-do-i-find-10-or-20/166323#166323) or [What quantity am I saying here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12250/what-quantity-am-i-saying-here)?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your example correctly, then the most clear would be:

```
Paints:

Eggshell (Matte)  x10

(...)
```

If this is the case, then you repeating "10" is potentially confusing. If you mean you have ten distinct categories of paints, then the reader can probably count that on their own.

However, if you mean that you have 10 units of each type of paint (e.g., 10 units of white paint, 10 units of black paint, ...) then you should only use 10 in the actual list.

As for your specific question about whether your example implies that you 20 units of paint of two different types, and not 10 units of paint of one type but with two qualities, then no, your wording doesn't imply that.

For example:

```
Paints:

Black and Glossy   x10

White and Matte   x10
```

reads as you having 10 units of paint with the qualities "Black" and "Glossy" and 10 units of paint with the qualities "White" and "Matte"

If you want to be even more clear, consider dropping the "and" and placing the secondary quality in parentheses.

A complete list might look something like:

```
Paints:

White (Glossy)             | x10
Black (Glossy)             | x10
White (Matte)              | x10
Black (Matte)              | x10
Orange (Glow-in-the-Dark)  | x10
Yellow (Glossy)            | x10

(...)
```

Note the separation of types and quantities, and the hierarchy or information with the parentheses. It's more of a document design thing, than an English Language and Usage thing, but it helps clarity.

Answer (score -2):

Paint is a non-countable object, like water.  Most liquids and fine powders are not countable.  When the noun is uncountable, you have to use a word that is countable, and that word gets changes to plural.  For "paint," some examples are below:

10 types of paint

10 colors of paint

10 buckets of paint

10 liters of paint

Comment: But aren't liquids and powders non-countable as well?

Comment: I think paints is correct here, as it would be in “10 blue paints.”

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paint) disagrees, at least when paints are in discrete units like trays in a paintbox or presumably cans on a shelf.

Comment: @Stuart F I'd guess there is a state of flux in the countification of _paint_. While I'm happy with 'these acrylic paints are good for beginners' and happyish with 'there are different paints for different purposes', I find  'we have a total of 100 paints in the storeroom' at best ambiguous, and probably unidiomatic.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See the guidance on "material nouns".